# В чем сложность и разница работы между запросами HTTP Get, Post vs HTTPS Get, Post?

Tags: http, post, get, https

В чем разница при использовании Http vs Https в запросах к серверу? И подскажите что можно почтить в это направлении?

Comment: никакой разницы нет. главное не смешивать на одном сайте оба протокола, иначе наткнетесь на кучу запретов безопасности